# Interpretation of Value at Risk and its relationship with the upper percentile

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, percentile

I found this definition of VaR (Value at Risk) in a paper:

VaR is defined as the “possible maximum loss over a given holding period within a fixed confidence level”. That is, mathematically, VaR at the $100(1 − α)%$ confidence level is defined as the upper 100α percentile of the loss distribution. Suppose X is a random variable denoting the loss of a given portfolio. Following Artzner et al. (1999), we define VaR at the $100(1 − α)%$ confidence level $(VaR_α(X))$ as

$VaR_α(X) = sup\{x|P[X \geq x] > α\}$

I am really struggling to understand what do they mean with upper percentile and how to understand this definition using a graph with the density.

Comment: They give a formal definition....informally, if you want confidence at the $90\%$ level, say, you take the loss distribution, lop off the worst $10\%$ of cases and take the cutoff.  Then, with probability $90\%$, you won't experience losses worse than that cutoff.

Comment: I get that, the idea is very clear actually, I cannot understand how that definition models this idea. How can be the $P[X \geq x]$ be bigger than alpha? And also I do not understand how the VaR is the sup of this set and not the inf.

Comment: What do you mean?v$P(X≥x)>a$ means that the probability that the loss will exceed $x$ is greater than $a$.  If you have a stock which will either make or lose  $\$1$ with equal probability, then $P(X>0)=.5$.  Of course, as $x$ increases, the probability goes down.  For my stock example, $P(X>.6)=0$.  The definition uses the sup because it represents the biggest possible loss under the given probability assumption.

Comment: When you are planning for a walk, you think about dressing for rain because there's a $10\%$ chance of rain that day.  You don't bother preparing for a tornado, even though that's a far more serious event, because you have decided that it's too improbable to bother with.  Rain is the worst condition probable enough to justify taking any steps.

Answer (score 0):

For the following argument, it will be better if you can depict them by sketching the survival function $S(x) = \Pr\{X \geq x\}$ in various situtions.

If the CDF of the loss distribution is continuous, then by intermediate value theorem, there exist $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\Pr\{X \geq x^*\} = \alpha$.

Further more, if the CDF is strictly increasing, i.e. the survival function is strictly decreasing, then such $x^*$ is unique for every given $\alpha$. Since only a single point satisfying the condition, the supremum is just $x^*$ itself.

If the survival function is only monotonic decreasing, and it happens to stay at the value $\alpha$ on an interval $I$, then there are infinite number of $x^* \in I$ satisfying $\Pr\{X \geq x^*\} = \alpha$. In such case, taking supremum means taking the right end point of the interval $I$, and therefore by taking supremum, this definition ensure the resulting value is unique.

The remaining case is when the survival function has jump discontinuity. So for some given $\alpha$, there may not exist $x$ satisfying $\Pr\{X \geq x\} = \alpha$, i.e. the survival function jumps from a value larger than $\alpha$, to a value less than $\alpha$. We cannot find the root of the above equation, so it will be an incomplete definition for VaR if we define this way.

To complete the definition, we simply take the largest $x$ that $\Pr\{X \geq x^*\} \geq \alpha$ which is the given definition. If you sketch the graph, it is simply the jump discontinutity point that jump over $\alpha$.